# how to apply functions on multiple excel sheets in a loop in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a excel file with a data like this on 57 sheets

```
  Cate  asso_num
1  "a"    33
2  "a"    67
3  "b"    97
4  "b"    60
```

i want to group by and get the mean of each category

```
def grouping( excel_file_location):
           # should read all the excel sheets i.e 57 sheets currently in a loop (i dont know how to do it)
           fil = pd.read_excel(...)
           fil = fil.groupby("Cate").agg({"asso_num":"mean"})
           # and should write in that same excel sheet
```

I want it do it from by writing function only

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def grouping(excel_file_location):
    sheets_to_df= pd.read_excel(excel_file_location, sheet_name=None)
    df = pd.concat(sheets_to_df, ignore_index=True)
    df = df.groupby("Cate").agg({"asso_num":"mean"})
    return df
```

So. In my example I created an excel with the data you provided and made three sheets with exact copies of it and gave:

```
path = r"C:\....\SDEGOSSONDEVARENNE\Sheets.xlsx"
```

Doing `grouping(path)`

returned:

```
      asso_num
Cate          
a         50.0
b         78.5
```

You can also reset the index

```
grouping(path).reset_index()
```

which gives

```
  Cate  asso_num
0    a      50.0
1    b      78.5
```